# Force page rendering after new HTML is loaded by AJAX

Tags: magento2, css, ajax, render, ui

I have a 3rd party extension for layered navigation in Magento 2.2.1. Products listing is repainted (using ajax) after customer changed the navigation filter (categories)  There is some visual error in product details after new HTML code loaded with ajax is inserted into the DOM (all products on the page have the same failure):

[image: Before window resize]

This failure is disappeared after browser window is resized manually:

[image: After window resize]

I have tried to use `$(window).trigger('resize')` but unsuccessfully:

```
    updateContent: function (url, updateState) {
        ...
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp instanceof Object) {
                    /* replace inner HTML for products listing with new one */
                    $(window).trigger('resize'); // does not work :(
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Does any method exist to refresh/repaint/render the page programmatically after HTML was changed?

The same effect (wrong order of the blocks then right order) exists on the page loading - wrong order leave about 1 second while page is loading and blocks order is restructured after the page is completely loaded. I believe there is some Magento JS function that does something like I need.

Comment: Have you check consol or log file when page load first time?

Comment: yes, no errors are in browser console.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to wrap your productCollection within any custom HTML id. Once done you will need to append it to the product wrapper like create block and use plugin to rewrite CategoryViewBlock

And do something like:-

```
class CategoryViewBlock
{
    const PRODUCT_LISTING_WRAPPER = 'custom-ajax-wrapper';


    public function afterToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($subject->getNameInLayout() == 'category.products.list' || $subject->getNameInLayout() == 'search_result_list') {
            $result = '<div class="' . self::PRODUCT_LISTING_WRAPPER . '">' . $result . '</div>';
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then you can name this wrapper id in any block which is being used in your

> magento-init phtml file

like:-

```
$config = [            
            'productsContainer' => '.' . \VendorName\LayeredNavigation\Plugin\CategoryViewBlock::PRODUCT_LISTING_WRAPPER
        ];
        return json_encode($config);
```

Now, I assume you must have used a block to configure result in your js using phtml file, so no change will be needed there. So just use this code in your js file:-

```
$(self.options.productsContainer).replaceWith(resp.products);
```

So it will become something like:-

```
updateContent: function (url, updateState) {
        ...
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp instanceof Object) {
                    /* replace inner HTML for products listing with new one */
               $(window).trigger('resize'); // does not work :(
               $(self.options.productsContainer).replaceWith(resp.products);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: exactly the same code is in the extension:
`$(self.options.filtersContainer).replaceWith(resp.leftnav);
$(self.options.productsContainer).replaceWith(resp.products);`

and this code gives a wrong formatting until window resize will be applied.

Comment: Are you using some custom theme? Can you try on default Luma theme if it works? As the issue can be on the theme.

Comment: Yes, I use [Fluid Responsive Magento Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798). I did not try Luma theme but I suppose (I'm sure ) it works in Luma theme.

Comment: And if you disable the theme does the module then work?

Comment: Yes, layered navigation works with Luma theme.

Comment: So that means that the issue lies with the theme js, and you will need to investigate with theme theme js files. There must be some js which is being used  on product listing file which is conflicting with the js of the module